# Function makeTextSprite not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use the function [makeTextSprite](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Topology-Data.html) without success and I can't understand the reason. Only the call to the function makes the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/g7oqexr8/5/) (line 53-54)(`var spritey = makeTextSprite( "XX", 
        { fontsize: 24,borderColor: {r:255, g:0, b:0, a:1.0},  backgroundColor: {r:255, g:100, b:100, a:0.8} } );` ) to not work.

I think I included all the resources necessary to makeTextSprite works.
My final goal is to create axis with labels for ticks in [each direction](http://www.fatiando.org/dev/_images/sphx_glr_mayavi-exaggerate_001.png), maybe another solution is easier to implement.

Comment: First, the jsFiddle is throwing up errors: 'Undefined old' and it renders nothing. Fixing that gets the jsFiddle to run/render. Second, the lines (55-56) to position and add the sprite to the scene are commented out. After uncommenting those lines, I see the text-sprite rendered as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in this part. I commented lines 55-56 to show that only calling the makeTextSprite function breaks my code. I did what you said but nothing appear (just a black background), but when I comment line 53-56 the scene appears (without the text-sprite). I'm not seeing the error you mentioned ('Undefined old'), where's it (I'm using Chrome)?

Comment: Ahh I see. Anyway, in both Chrome and Firefox, I see an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: old is not defined" ... referring to lines 81 and 117. As far as I can tell, this error is the reason the scene doesn't render: adding var old = false; to the top of the jsFiddle code fixes that. Then un-commenting those lines (55-56) causes the textSprite to show as expected. Here's the updated jsFiddle where I see no errors and see the textSprite operational: http://jsfiddle.net/g7oqexr8/6/